# Socket.io: Connect from one server to another

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a nodejs(socket.io) server to communicate with another one.
So the client emits an event to the 'hub' server and this server emits an event to some second server for processing the action.

I tried to do:

```
var io_client = require( 'socket.io-client' );
```

and then,

```
io_client.connect( "second_server_host" );
```

it seems to work for connection but you can't do anything with this:

```
debug - set close timeout for client 15988842591410188424
info  - socket error Error: write ECONNABORTED
 at errnoException (net.js:642:11)
 at Socket._write (net.js:459:18)
 at Socket.write (net.js:446:15)
```

I guess I'm doing it wrong and missing something obvious.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens on "second_server_host"? Does it accept the connection properly? Does it close the connection prematurely? Do you check for closed connection?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the log is from the "second" server. It accepts connection, so the connection callback `io.sockets.on('connection', connection_callback )` is being called, but it fails when I try to set callbacks on certain events i.e. `socket.on('server_to_server_command', command_callback)` with the error log above (ECONNABORTED). I just suppose I shouldn't use socket.io-client on server at all, there must be a way to do these inter-servers communications properly..

Comment: OK, it seems to be fixed very recently, here is the thread http://groups.google.com/group/socket_io/browse_thread/thread/e12b27f2b16ec8eb?pli=1

Comment: please consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 10):

Just came across this question, and another just like it with a much better answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14118102/1068746

You can do server to server. The "client" code remains the same as if it was on the browser. Amazing isn't it?

I just tried it myself, and it works fine..

I ran 2 servers - using the same exact code - once on port 3000 as server, and another on port 3001 as client. The code looks like this:

```
  , io = require('socket.io')
  , ioClient = require('socket.io-client')

   .... 

   if ( app.get('port') == 3000 ){

    io.listen(server).sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
}else{
    function emitMessage( socket ){
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
        setTimeout(function(){emitMessage(socket)}, 1000);
    }
    var socket = ioClient.connect("http://localhost:3000");
    emitMessage(socket);
}
```

And if you see on the server side a "{my:data}" print every second, everything works great. Just make sure to run the client (port 3001) after the server (port 3000).

Comment: This must be missing a first line where you create this app object?

Comment: yes. this is out of the scope for this question. you can use express generator `npm -g install express` and then `express` to quickly generate this code. You can probably find a copy paste example online. its quite easy

Answer (score 7):

For anyone searching for a short **working example,** see below. This example works with `socket.io@0.9.16` and `socket.io-client@0.9.16`.

```
var port = 3011;

var server = require( 'http' ).createServer( ).listen( port, function () {
    console.log( "Express server listening on port " + port );
} );

var io = require( 'socket.io' ).listen( server ).set( "log level", 0 );

io.sockets.on( "connection", function ( socket ) {
    console.log( 'Server: Incoming connection.' );
    socket.on( "echo", function ( msg, callback ) {
        callback( msg );
    } );
} );


var ioc = require( 'socket.io-client' );
var client = ioc.connect( "http://localhost:" + port );

client.once( "connect", function () {
    console.log( 'Client: Connected to port ' + port );

    client.emit( "echo", "Hello World", function ( message ) {
        console.log( 'Echo received: ', message );
        client.disconnect();
        server.close();
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

For Server to Server or App to App communication, I think you should look into Redis Pub-sub. Its capable of very good speeds, and can handle the entire message queuing architecture of a big app.

Here is a slightly complex but quite understandable example for using Redis Pub Sub:
[Redis Pub Sub Example](http://howtonode.org/redis-pubsub)

Comment: this belongs in a comment -- it's a suggestion, not an answer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to do this on a [MeteorJS](http://meteor.com) app, I created a new Meteor package `joncursi:socket-io-client` to solve this problem. Please see https://atmospherejs.com/joncursi/socket-io-client for more detail and example usage. Since I've bundled the NPM binaries into a package for you, you don't have to worry about installing NPM packages, declaring `NPM.require()` dependencies, etc. And best of all, you can deploy to `.meteor.com` without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

`ECONNABORTED` means that the connection have been closed by "the other side".

For example, lets say we have two programs, A and B. Program A connects to program B, and they start to send data back and forth. Program B closes the connection for some reason. After the connection was closed program A tries to write to program B, but since the connection is closed program A will get the error `ECONNABORTED`.

One of your programs have closed the connection, and the other doesn't know about it and tries to write to the socket, resulting in an error.

Answer (score 0):

The native Node TCP module is probably what you want - I wanted to do what you're trying to do but it seems that the fact that WebSockets are strictly many-browser to server, or browser to many-server.

You can weave a tcp strategy into your websocket logic.

Using tcp:

```
var net = require('net');
var tcp = net.connect({port: 3000, host: 'localhost'});
tcp.on('connect', function(){
  var buffer = new Buffer(16).fill(0);
  buffer.write('some stuff');
  tcp.write(buffer);
});

tcp.on('data', function(data){console.log('data is:', data)});
tcp.on('end', cb);
tcp.on('error', cb);
```

I would use a bridge pattern with this:

https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+bridge+pattern&aq=f&oq=javascript+bridge+pattern&aqs=chrome.0.57.6617&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

OR, use the Node Module https://npmjs.org/package/ws-tcp-bridge

I also heard that using redis can be quite helpful - Socket.io uses this as a fallback.

Hope this helps...

Cheers