# socket.io is not handling connection from socket.io-client from other node.js server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

There are two servers and I want to emit some events from server2 to server1 but facing an issue.
SERVER1 is working fine when I try to connect it from other client tool(firecamp), but same code is not working when init socket from SERVER2 using socket.io-client.
here is code snippets :-
SERVER1

```
socket.io.on('connection', (client) => {

console.log("Socket has been Connected");

client.on("server custom event",(data)=>{
    console.log("custom event");
})
})
```

OUTPUT OF SERVER1

[image]

It continuously connecting and disconnecting socket. but I did not receive any message in SERVER2.

SERVER2 CODE

```
var ioclient = require("socket.io-client")
var ioc = ioclient.connect('http://localhost:3000');
ioc.on('connect', function () {
// socket connected
console.log("connected");
});
ioc.emit('server custom event', { my: 'data' });
```

SERVER2 just show the message "server is running on port 8080".

I follow this:
[Socket IO Server to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118076/socket-io-server-to-server/14118102#14118102)