# Using Socket.io to be the server and the client

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

How do I make a server that has a socket connecting to one client(Client A) also have a socket to another server? Basically how do I have the server become a client as well(to another server)?

If the answer is to load the socket.io-client then how would I do that in a javascript file?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var http2 = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("asdf");
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3050, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3050');
});


http2.listen(1337, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:1330');
});



var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:1337');
socket.on('connect', function(){

  console.log('connected');
});
```

Comment: Check this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16767264/2811859

Comment: Actually I looked it over and the link on that and those were from two years ago. Socket.io has gotten a complete write up if I am correct and a lot of the methods have completely changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to run a node server as a client since you mention javascript file. Here is how to set up a socket client in node. Get the package `npm i socket.io-client`. Then use it in node as shown below.

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:1337');
socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log('connected')
});
```

Comment: I assume I had to first create the server at 1337 so I added some code which I have put in an edit. However, it never prints 'connected'. Did I put the code in the wrong place or...?

Comment: You're very close.. all you need to do is create your socket instance on port 3050. `var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3050');`